# Getting data using Regular Expressions - PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have html text stored in one of the columns of a database. the column name is mailbody and the table name is inbox_master.

Some the cells of column `mailbody` has divs like below

```
<div id="uid-g-uid" style="">2802</div>
```

or

```
<div id="uid-g-uid">
<p class="MsoNormal">6894</p>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="uid-g-uid" style="display:none;">
6894</div>
```

what is common here is a div with the id "uid-g-uid". I want to be able to read the html of this div. I know this could be done using regular expressions however, not sure how to do it.

Below is the regex that i have tried but doesnt work all the time

```
/(?<=\<div\ id\=\"uid\-g\-uid\").*?(?=\<\/div\>)/gim
```

Comment: You should use DOM and not regex. So much easier.

Comment: great! can you suggest some articles i can read and learn! Dont have any experience on DOM :-(

Comment: @gunjansoni2002 ~ google is you friend. Here's DOM PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @sikfire and @dave, i got the solution using DOM. below is my working which helped me

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML('The HTML Content Goes here');
$d = $doc->getElementById('uid-g-uid');
echo 'Value is ' . $d['textContent'];
```

Didnt knew this could be this simple! Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 1):

you can also look at the project here. [PHP DomParser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

This might help!